# SQLite Database Locked Exception when Insert query in for loop

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am using  **SQLite Database**. When I'am Executing the Below Code is show an error **database is locked** . Please help me where is I'am wrong and how to solve the Database is locked error
Below are My Code:

```
    Try
       Dim i As Integer = 0
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(constring)
         Dim insertsquery As String = "insert into EnergyMeterDetails(DateTime, ElectricitySupplyer, ElectricityMeterNo,ElectricityMeterModelName, MultiplyingFactor, ConsumerNo, TarrifCode, Category,TypeOfSupply, HT_LT, EnergyMeterNo, EnergyMeterName, EnergyMeterLocation, EnergyMeterModel)VALUES(@DateTime, @ElectricitySupplyer, @ElectricityMeterNo,@ElectricityMeterModelName, @MultiplyingFactor, @ConsumerNo, @TarrifCode, @Category,@TypeOfSupply, @HT_LT,@EnergyMeterNo, @EnergyMeterName, @EnergyMeterLocation, @EnergyMeterModel)"

            Dim cmdsql As  New SQLiteCommand(insertsquery, con)
            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@DateTime", Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@ElectricityMeterNo", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@ElectricitySupplyer", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@ElectricityMeterModelName", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@MultiplyingFactor", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@ConsumerNo", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@TarrifCode", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@Category", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@TypeOfSupply", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@HT_LT", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@EnergyMeterNo", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@EnergyMeterName", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@EnergyMeterLocation", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value))
                cmdsql.Parameters.Add(New SQLiteParameter("@EnergyMeterModel", DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value))


                con.Open()
                If cmdsql.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                    MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED SUCCESSFULLY")
                    status = True
                End If
                con.Close()
            Next

        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why would you be opening and closing the connection inside the loop? You open the connection once first and you don't close it because that will happen automatically at the `End Using` line.

Comment: If you read about databinding you can do all that in one simple statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't keep adding parameters over and over inside the loop. Just add them once and reset the values inside the loop.

```
Private Sub SaveToSQLite()
    Try
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        Using con As New SQLiteConnection(constring)
            Dim insertsquery As String = "insert into EnergyMeterDetails(DateTime, ElectricitySupplyer, ElectricityMeterNo,ElectricityMeterModelName, MultiplyingFactor, ConsumerNo, TarrifCode, Category,TypeOfSupply, HT_LT, EnergyMeterNo, EnergyMeterName, EnergyMeterLocation, EnergyMeterModel)VALUES(@DateTime, @ElectricitySupplyer, @ElectricityMeterNo,@ElectricityMeterModelName, @MultiplyingFactor, @ConsumerNo, @TarrifCode, @Category,@TypeOfSupply, @HT_LT,@EnergyMeterNo, @EnergyMeterName, @EnergyMeterLocation, @EnergyMeterModel)"

            Dim cmdsql As New SQLiteCommand(insertsquery, con)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@ElectricityMeterNo", DbType.Int64)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@ElectricitySupplyer", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@ElectricityMeterModelName", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@MultiplyingFactor", DbType.Decimal)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@ConsumerNo", DbType.Int64)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@TarrifCode", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@Category", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@TypeOfSupply", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@HT_LT", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@EnergyMeterNo", DbType.Int64)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@EnergyMeterName", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@EnergyMeterLocation", DbType.String)
            cmdsql.Parameters.Add("@EnergyMeterModel", DbType.String)
            con.Open()
            For i = 0 To DataGridView1.Rows.Count - 2
                cmdsql.Parameters("@DateTime").Value = Format(Now, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                cmdsql.Parameters("@ElectricityMeterNo").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@ElectricitySupplyer").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@ElectricityMeterModelName").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(2).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@MultiplyingFactor").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@ConsumerNo").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(4).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@TarrifCode").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(5).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@Category").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(6).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@TypeOfSupply").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(7).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@HT_LT").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(8).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@EnergyMeterNo").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(9).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@EnergyMeterName").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(10).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@EnergyMeterLocation").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(11).Value
                cmdsql.Parameters("@EnergyMeterModel").Value = DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(12).Value

                cmdsql.ExecuteNonQuery()
                status = True
            Next
            MessageBox.Show("DATA ADDED SUCCESSFULLY")
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

I have just guessed at data types. Check your datatbase for actual types.